# Javascript control for modeling 2D, 3D data

Tags: javascript, open-source

Does any know JS lib for vizualizing/modeling data in 2D/3D formats (3D MAX model, ANSYS, or just txt file)?
It will be fine if it will be free.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to be more specific about what kinds of formats you wish to visualize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lib that allows you to load and display both 2d and 3d models would be [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/).

It allows you to setup an entire scene with lighting and such.